# Bounce rate when sending to twitter for login?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, bounce

I just realized that my bounce rate numbers may be wrong...
Does my bounce rate in google analytics take into account that users are taken from the landing page through twitter's login authorization and back to my site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Try firing event call on click of twitter while keeping `nonInteraction` as `false`. It should help in reducing the bounce rate for twitter. Code reference is here (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) and (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hit)

Assuming you're using analytics.js - universal analytics.